# "VitePWA(vite-plugin-pwa)" is not generating all icons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, build, progressive-web-apps, vite

I'm using ReactJS with Vite and trying to make a PWA with vite-plugin-pwa. However, the plugin is not generating all the icons specified in my manifest object.It generate only 4 icons(including favicon.ico).

- *apple-touch-icon.png*
- *mask-icon.svg*
- *cr.jpg*
- and *favicon.ico* by default

Here is my code:

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import { VitePWA } from "vite-plugin-pwa";

const manifestForPlugin = {
    registerType: "prompt",
    includeAssets: ["favicon.ico", "pwa-icon-512.png", "android-chrome-512x512.png", "apple-touch-icon.png", "mask-icon.svg", "cr.jpg"], //I tried adding/removing icon name from here but , no change, generate the 4 icons only 

    manifest: {
        name: "App name",
        short_name: "short name",
        description: "desc...",
        icons: [
            {
                src: "src/assets/img/pwa-icon-512.png", //dosen't generate

                sizes: "512x512",
                type: "image/png",
                purpose: "any maskable",
            },
            {
                src: "src/assets/img/android-chrome-512x512.png", //dosen't generate
                sizes: "512x512",
                type: "image/png",
                purpose: "any maskable",
            },
            {
                src: "src/assets/img/apple-touch-icon.png",
                sizes: "180x180",
                type: "image/png",
                purpose: "apple touch icon",
            },
            {
                src: "src/assets/img/mask-icon.svg",
                sizes: "144x65",
                type: "image/svg+xml",
                purpose: "any maskable",
            },
            {
                src: "src/assets/img/cr.jpg",
                sizes: "457x450",
                type: "image/jpg",
                purpose: "any maskable",
            }
        ],
        theme_color: "#1e1e1e",
        background_color: "#1e1e1e",
        display: "standalone",
        scope: "/",
        start_url: "/",
        orientation: "portrait",
    },
};
// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    base: "./",
    plugins: [react(), VitePWA(manifestForPlugin)],
    build: {//I also tried adding/removing this build object but still it generate only the 4 icon
        outDir: "dist",
    },
});
```

I also changed the position of the icon object but no matter what I do It just generate the 4 icon only.

In network tab it throws 404 error for the files that I'm trying to add.

Here is my folder tree:

[folder tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ibyG.jpg)

pnpm buld result:

[build tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZ1I8.jpg)

I tried moving all the icons to public folder and rename the src path but it still generate the 4 icons only.